# TCP/IP problems after uninstalling software

Tags: windows-xp, networking, ip

I installed some type of Bit-Torrent software.  I used it for a day and then I UN-installed it.  But, now I have no IP on that computer --- can not even get on my local NAS LAN.   I tried reinstalling the Intel drivers for the 470 and tried some things like this:
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/298-completely-rebuild-the-tcp-ip-stack#
But, I did not get my IP back.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: Which software did you install? How did yo uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is a slight variation of the link you posted.

Open Network Connections

Right click on the network adapter you use and select properties.

A window opens

Now click "Install" Button

A windows opens

Select "Protocol" then click "Add" button

a windows opens

Do not select a protocol, just Click "Have Disk" button

a window opens

Click "Browse"

Navigate to

> C:\Windows\inf

find "nettcpip.inf" and highlight it and click "Open"

this will overwrite the tcpip stack with a fresh copy, see if this gets it working for you.

Click OK on all the windows.

.

[image]